# Finding the occurrence of an integer from an array in a file:

Tags: java, arrays

I have to find how many times the integer 50 occurs in this array that was created from numbers in a text file and then output how many students got a perfect score of 50, but I seem to be stuck in an infinite loop at the end? I have to use arrays and I must also use methods as well. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class TestScores
{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
      int count=0;
      int number;

      //Open the file
      File file=new File("scores.txt");
      Scanner inputFile=new Scanner(file);

      //Count the number of elements in the file 
      while(inputFile.hasNext())
      {
         number=inputFile.nextInt();
         count++;
      }

      //Close the file 
      inputFile.close();

      //Create an array      
      int[] numbers=new int[count];

      //Display the number of elements in the array 
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, count); 

      //Pass the array to the loadData method
      loadData(numbers);   

     //Pass the array to the perfectScore method
      perfectScore(numbers);
  }       

 /**
     The loadData method loads the data from the file into the array
     @param array A reference to the array
  */

 public static void loadData(int[] array) throws IOException
 {
     int index=0;
     //Open the file
     File file=new File("scores.txt");
     Scanner inputFile=new Scanner(file);
     //load the data from the file into the array
     while(inputFile.hasNext() && index<array.length)
     {
        array[index]=inputFile.nextInt();
        index++;
     }
  }

  /**
     The perfectScore method determines how many students 
     got a 50 on the exam.
     @param array A reference to the array
  */

  public static void perfectScore(int[] array)
  {
     for(int index=0; index<array.length; index++)
    {
        if(array[index]==50)
        {
           index++;
           int perfect=array[index];
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number of students " +
           "who got a perfect 50 score is: "+ perfect + " students.");
        }
     }
   }  
}
```

Comment: Which loop you reckon is going to be infinite? Mind that in `perfectScore(int[] array)` you are incrementing `index`, which is already being incremented by the `for loop` itself. You should have another variable, let's say `grades_count` to keep track of scores of 50 and increment that one. As other said, `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` should be called after the loop, otherwise you'll have a new window at each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void perfectScore(int[] array)  {
    int count = 0;
    for(int index=0; index<array.length; index++){
       if(array[index]==50) {
         //  index++;  // don't increment this
           count++;

       }
    }
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number of students " +
           "who got a perfect 50 score is: "+count + " students.");
}
```

- Don't increment index for the count. Increment some other variable like
  `count`
- And move the OptionPane outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

So in your for - if block because you are giving message to user everytime when it find 50! Why would you do that? I mean just count in that block and in the end show to user just the result! No?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public static void perfectScore(int[] arr) {

    int count = 0;

    int len = arr.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 50)
            count++;
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number of students who got a perfect 50 score is: " + count + " students.");

}
```

You are calling JOptionPane.showMessageDialog for every student with score 50.
But java will pause after opening one dialog (It will continue once the dialog is closed, but you are doing this for every student with a score of 50).

Answer (score 0):

- Don't read the file twice. Read once and load into an array
- Iterate an array and increase count if you find 50
- Finally, display the message.

Problem with this code is, you are incrementing the index again once you find the 50 value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Java8:

```
int count = IntStream.range(0, array.length).filter(index -> array[index] == 50).count();
```

Or ([by @Abra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61552000/finding-the-occurrence-of-an-integer-from-an-array-in-a-file/61552176?noredirect=1#comment108880104_61552176)):

```
IntStream.of(array).filter(score -> score == 50).count();
```

Comment: Alternatively: `IntStream.of(array).filter(score -> score == 50).count();`